# how to find difference between no_of_value and no_of_distinct columns values?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let  be the number of CITY entries in STATION, and let  be the number of distinct CITY names in STATION; query the value of  from STATION. In other words, find the difference between the total number of CITY entries in the table and the number of distinct CITY entries in the table.

Input Format

The STATION table is described as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQxaP.jpg)

where LAT_N is the northern latitude and LONG_W is the western longitude.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Jeyasri .R.  Your STATION table is very simple.  It is much better practice to include it as a data table (formatted as code) than as an image.  Your question is unclear.  This may be due to grammatical problems.  Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you missing some text (perhaps some variable names)? Also, why do you explain latitude and longitude, they don't seem related to your question?

Comment: I came searching for this from hackerrank :-D same question there.

Answer (score 4):

Use distinct in count function.

```
select count(city) - count(distinct city) 
from station
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(city) - count(DISTINCT city) FROM station;
```

Do not forget to add semicolon ';' after the query

Answer (score 0):

You could use having  for filtering the resul on aggregated  function

```
 select city,  count(*), count(distinct city) 
 from station
 group by city
 having count(*) <> count(distinct city)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select count(city) - count(distinct city)
from station;
```

You would do this to get the number of duplicated values in the table.  I might be more interested in the list of cities and the number of duplicates:

```
select city, count(*) - 1 as numdups
from station
group by city
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you select count(city) - count(distinct city)
from station; this query executed properly